# Powershell silently fails to stop process?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've never seen anything like this happen and am not even sure I understand how it is possible. The `Stop-Process` seems to complete fine but the process is running untouched. I've tried with an admin console and without. What could be going on?

```
PS Y:\> ps dev*

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
   2411    4208   352360     305312   953   101.66   7060   1 devenv
   3680     392   529640     647148  1349   714.81  12056   1 devenv


PS Y:\> kill 7060 -Force -Verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Stop-Process" on target "devenv (7060)".
PS Y:\> ps dev*

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------
   2411    4209   352360     305312   953   101.66   7060   1 devenv
   3680     392   529640     647148  1349   714.81  12056   1 devenv
```

I'll note btw that I'm suspicious that this process is locking a certain dll file. Trying to delete the file says its locked by msbuild, but LockHunter says the file is not being locked, yet its Delete button is greyed out.

To clarify, the question isn't "what should I do?" Obviously a system reboot would kill the process, but rather how can this command possibly report a success without actually killing the process? What might be going on internally?

Comment: `where /R c:\ devenv` returns `.exe` as well as `.com`. Maybe this could be worth to know: what output from `ps dev* | ft -property ID, name, Path`

Comment: @JosefZ I've already restarted the VM so can't really answer further questions but I don't see how the path can matter if I'm passing in the process id

Comment: Aren't you supposed to kill spawned processes as well?

Comment: @DavidBrabant You mean the entire process tree? I don't see how its necessary for `Stop-Process` If it were, it would fail relatively frequently yet I've never seen this happen before. For the record, I *did* before I restarted try process explorer and ended process tree, but 7060 remained and when I tried to get procexp to kill it directly I got an "access denied" popup. Process explorer of course is running as admin.